# Android EditText with numeric input type : the increment doesn't work

Tags: android, android-edittext, increment

I have an `EditText` edit_text with numeric input type and I want to do an increment of the variable in it when I press the button "+". I try this code but doesn't work.

I get a `FATAL EXCEPTION`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String value = edit_text.getText().toString();
    int value_int = Integer.parseInt(value);
    int incremento = value_int +1 ;
    edit_text.setText(incremento);
}
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: Change your code to edit_text.setText(incremento+""); or edit_text.setText(String.valueOf(incremento));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
edit_text.setText(incremento);
```

This line giving you the error. Change that to.

```
edit_text.setText(String.valueOf(incremento));
```

Reason is that you can not directly put an `int` in `setText()` as it tries to find a resource with an `id` corresponding to you `int` and fails.

Answer (score 0):

update this..

```
edit_text.setText(""+incremento);
```

since setText() required String as argument not the Integer...hence concenating the "" with the integer return String which is finally required

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @iAnum .. my answer seems right although. i don't think any difference with the other answer posted simultaneously.although the answer was not brief. i.e. why the author found FATAL EXCEPTION. i hope the mine updated answer will somehow satify you..

Comment: Well, now it seems better :)

Comment: i appreciate your observation @iAnum :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String value=edit_text.getText().toString();
            int value_int=Integer.parseInt(value);
            int incremento=value_int +1 ;
            edit_text.setText(incremento.toString());

        }
    });
```

Some notes tho:

1. Depending on the input type, numeric should be used with int/integer and decimal with double/Double. You must take care of converting string/double/int because the conversion may sometimes not be possible, so you need to handle that cases.
2. You can convert from int to string in two possible ways:

   - edit_text.setText(incremento + "");
   - edit_text.setText(String.valueOf(incremento));